# Select2 is showing "No result found" message when selecting second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 with ajax option and its a multiple selection box. I am able to select the record first time. But after selecting first one if i try to select the next one it is not working.

[fiddle link for complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/sbdr183t)

```
$('#select2_ajax_complex_id').select2({
    tags: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 10,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    multiple: true,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    placeholder: "Search Employee",
    //data:o,
    id: function(i) {
      return i;
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {

    },
    ajax: {
      type: 'post',
      url: "/echo/json/",
      allowClear: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      params: {
        contentType: "application/json"
      },
      data: function(term, page) {
        //Code for dummy ajax response
        return {
          json: complex_employee_response,
          delay: 0
        };
      },
      results: function(data, page) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: false
    },
    formatResult: function(i) {
      return '<div>' + i.name + '(' + i.role + ')' + '</div>';
    }, // Formats results in drop down
    formatSelection: function(i) {
      return '<div>' + i.name + '(' + i.role + ')' + '</div>';
    }, //Formats result that is selected
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m;
      } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results          
  })
```

Can some one have a look and help to resolve this?

Comment: I have Edited the demo you have provided .the issue is fixed in it.Refer the answer for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove below  block from your code

```
//data:o,
id: function(i) {
  return i;
},
initSelection: function(element, callback) {

},
```

By using this code ,your problem will fixed

I have created one demo for the same[Edited in your example]

Just refer this URL

https://jsfiddle.net/7m2nv5yw/